# Как записать в переменную информацию введённую в QTextEdit по нажатию QPushButton? Расположено на QDockWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qdockwidget

Необходимо по нажатию `QPushButton`, записать введённую  в `QTextEdit` информацию в переменную, которая находится в `QDockWidget`.

При нажатии кнопки вылетает ошибка и программа закрывается:

> Failed to query stereo recording. 
> raceback (most recent call last):
> File "pp.py", line 99, in insertAll
> text_zhaloba = self.formazhalob.toPlainText()
> AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'formazhalob'\

Пробую так:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...  

        self.docked = QDockWidget("Программа!", self)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.docked)
        self.dockedWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.docked.setWidget(self.dockedWidget)
        self.dockedWidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        textzz = QLabel()
        textzz.setText('Тут будет текст')
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(textzz)
        formazhalob = QTextEdit()
        formazhalob.setText('Что то не работает? Напиши!')
        formazhalob.setFixedSize(190,100)
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(formazhalob)
        button_otpravka = QPushButton(('Отправить информацию'))
        button_otpravka.clicked.connect(self.insertAll)
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(button_otpravka)
    def insertAll(self):
        text_zhaloba = self.formazhalob.toPlainText()
        self.textzz.setText(text_zhaloba)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Не работает. Помогите разобраться. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class dockdemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dockdemo, self).__init__(parent)
        bar    = self.menuBar()
        file   = bar.addMenu("File")
        file.addAction("New")
        file.addAction("save")
        file.addAction("quit")

        self.dockedWidget      = QDockWidget("Dockable", self)

        self._inner_widget = QFrame(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self._inner_widget)

        self.dockedWidget.setWidget(self._inner_widget)
        self.dockedWidget.setFloating(False)

        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItems(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.formazhalob = QTextEdit()
        self.formazhalob.setText('Что то не работает? Напиши тут!')
        self.formazhalob.setFixedSize(190,100)
        layout.addWidget(self.formazhalob)

        button_otpravka = QPushButton(('Отправить информацию'))
        button_otpravka.clicked.connect(self.insertAll)
        layout.addWidget(button_otpravka)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dockedWidget)


    def insertAll(self):
        text = self.formazhalob.toPlainText()
        print(text)
        self.textEdit.setText(text)
        self.listWidget.addItem(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = dockdemo()
    ex.setWindowTitle("Dock demo")
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ваш рабочий пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.docked = QDockWidget("Программа!", self)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.docked)
        self.dockedWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.docked.setWidget(self.dockedWidget)
        self.dockedWidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.textzz = QLabel()                                   # + self.textzz
        self.textzz.setText('Тут будет текст')                   # + ...
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(self.textzz)
        self.formazhalob = QTextEdit()                           # + self.formazhalob
        self.formazhalob.setText('Что то не работает? Напиши!')  # ...
        self.formazhalob.setFixedSize(190,100)
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(self.formazhalob)
        button_otpravka = QPushButton(('Отправить информацию'))
        button_otpravka.clicked.connect(self.insertAll)
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(button_otpravka)

    def insertAll(self):
        text_zhaloba = self.formazhalob.toPlainText()
        self.textzz.setText(text_zhaloba)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорректировал свой код на следующий вариант:
        button_otpravka = QPushButton(('Отправить информацию'))
        button_otpravka.clicked.connect(self.insertAll)
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(button_otpravka)
и добавил

    def insertAll(self):
        text_zhaloba = self.formazhalob.toPlainText()
        print(text_zhaloba)
        self.textEdit.setText(text_zhaloba)

и при нажатии кнопки бъёт ошибку

Comment: Можете дать рабочий вариант для моего куска кода? Какую переменную я упускаю?

Comment: @yong  Какую ошибку вам выдает? Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Ошибка - Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Правда пример не знаю как в комментарии вставить кусок кода

Comment: 1. Пример надо публиковать в вопросе, после строк `Пробую так:`           . 2. Запустите свой код из командной строки - `python name.py` и вы все поймете.

Comment: Вот ошибка из командной

[2808:3640:0417/123601.461:ERROR:adm_helpers.cc(73)] Failed to query stereo recording.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pp.py", line 99, in insertAll
    text_zhaloba = self.formazhalob.toPlainText()
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'formazhalob'

Comment: Скорректировал тело вопроса

Comment: @yong я посмотрю, но первое что вам надо сделать, это добавить `self.` перед всеми `formazhalob`  -> `self.formazhalob`

Comment: @yong я добавил в ответ рабочий пример

Comment: @yong Если мой пример помог вам, не забудьте отметить его как правильный.

Comment: спасибо, всё помогло